# Custom UITableView - iOs

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, rss

I followed this tutorial on  creating a simple rss reader...

http://www.kieranmcgrady.com/blog/2012/4/25/tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-rss-reader-for-ios.html

The problem is that I am having problem with design since everything is done programmatically.

How would i go about making each cell a square that takes up the page and if i scroll down, it will go down to a new page showing the next cell?

Comment: If you want the view to scroll in discrete chunks, then you probably want something closer to a page view controller instead of a table view, try taking a look for some tutorials on how to do that

Comment: there are no tutorials on how to implement an rss feed in a uipageviewcontroller

Comment: You already know how to download and access the RSS information for the table view, just translate that information to be passed to something in a page view controller

Comment: @DylanKatz there were also no tutorials for John von Neumann on 'How to build a successful computer architecture'. Instead of relying on copying tutorials, try to... wait for it... THINK.

Comment: If your not going to be useful then don't comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are attempting to replicate the functionality of [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/). If that's the case, you may find this [article](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/28/how-does-the-reeder-iphone-app-swipe-up-and-down-between-articles/) and [GitHub project](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/VerticalSwipeArticles) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off (I think) using your own UIViewControllers with their own text/images and adding their views to a UIScrollView with paging enabled. If you are looking for some tutorials on how to use UIScrollView to achieve this perhpas [this](http://chrisoxley.me/?p=44) will be useful. Chances are you won't find exactly what you are looking for, you just need to divide your problem and then look for solutions. i.e. Read RSS feed. Create UIScrollView with pages. Create custom ViewControllers.